# Journey error message as "Quit without saving" even when there is no change done to the Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

It's a multi step Journey created. There is a new issue which is been observed in Journey builder, receiving an error message as "Quit without saving" even when there is no change done to the Journey. Is it something to be worried about? Kindly let me know what all things need to be checked in this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to figure out the answer for this that If I am using my Journey templates which are created by me and making some changes to it and saving the Journey. The system is asking relating to my Journey template which is not changed yet however the changes i have done to my other journey which is based on a template is different, hence I was getting this error message "Quit without saving". I have tested this multiple times and understood.

Points to remember:

1. Check each activity if you have made any changes to any activity.
2. Remember all activity steps what all information is been saved, so that nothing is escaped than your original plan by taking screenshots,images etc.
3. Discard changes or cancel option to be used if you are just viewing your journey activities.
4. If your Journey is made up of your templates then "My templates" then possibly you may end of receiving this error message.

Thank you!